# InvokeMember Click not working

Tags: vb.net

Here's my code

```
            Dim PageElements As HtmlElementCollection = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")
        For Each CurElement As HtmlElement In PageElements
            If InStr(CurElement.InnerHtml, "Sign In") Then
                CurElement.InvokeMember("click")
            End If
        Next
```

Picture of HTML: http://prntscr.com/611gpe

I have no idea what I should put there. That "Sign In" not working. What I need to change it with?

Comment: Use WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("signInButton")

Comment: Taking a screenshot of code (even HTML) is foul and unnatural. Copy and paste it into a code block.

Answer (score 0):

My first question is if you step through the debugger is it getting to the InvokeMember line or is the string comparison really not finding "Sign In" in the InnerHtml?

In the past with the webbrowser control I have had to put an "[Application.DoEvents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.doevents(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)" after InvokeMember (DoEvents processes all messages in the message queue).  It's horrible for performance but if you're hitting the InvokeMember line it may get your code working.

For instance, I have this extension method (off of the WebBrowser control) that clicks an element based on the ID in the current page or in any child frames (I went ahead and called the DoEvents otherwise it wouldn't work, performance wasn't really my goal here):

```
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Clicks the HTML elements.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="id"></param>
    ''' <param name="wb"></param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    <Extension()> _
    Public Sub ClickElement(ByVal wb As WebBrowser, ByVal id As String)
        If wb.Document Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

        If wb.Document.Window.Frames.Count > 0 Then
            For Each hw As HtmlWindow In wb.Document.Window.Frames
                hw.Document.GetElementById(id).InvokeMember("click")
            Next
        Else
            wb.Document.Window.Document.GetElementById(id).InvokeMember("click")
        End If

        Application.DoEvents()
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, i was trying to use invoke member click and it would not work,
The solution i found was before i used:

```
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("CertainButtonID").InvokeMember("click")
```

I inserted:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("CertainButtonID").InvokeMember("focus")
```

which made the code like this:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("CertainButtonID").InvokeMember("focus")
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("CertainButtonID").InvokeMember("click")
```

### hint

Use the Document.GetElementById instead of looping all elements in the document

Comment: Not woking for me I am able to access the inner text of my button, but InvokeMember("click") does nothing